# Python Tkinter: Placing buttons in frame

Tags: button, tkinter

I'm trying to create different frames and switch/destroy them so that you can move between windows like you would in a normal iOS app.

To do so, I need to place the widgets (components) in frames (containers).

However, when I try to add a button to the frame it doesn't pack it to the right side.

Here is my code:
    from tkinter import *

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Good morning :)')

frame1=Frame(root,width=500,height=500,bg='green')
frame1.pack()

button1=Button(frame1,text='Hello')
button1.pack(side='bottom')
```

Comment: you forgot `root.mainloop()`

Comment: Why do you think any of the widgets should go to the right side? There's nothing in your code that is even trying to do that. You say you've "tried everything", so show us more than just one thing you've tried.

Comment: Here is the canonical documentation for how `pack` works: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26

Comment: if you have only `Button` inside then you can't see that it is on any side. `Buttton` fill entire `Frame` and `Frame` doesn't fill entire window. Try `frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to expand the Frame to fill the entire top-level window, and you need to tell the Button to pack on `side='right'` instead of `side='bottom'`.
And you need to run `root.mainloop()` at the end.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Good morning :)')

frame1 = Frame(root, bg='green')
frame1.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

button1 = Button(frame1, text='Hello')
button1.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Also, you don't need the dimensions in the Frame statement, since it will expand to the full 500x500 stated in the geometry with the extra keyword arguments passed to the pack() function.  By default, the Frame is only going to be big enough to hold the widgets inside it, so it will only be as big as the Button, unless you tell it to expand to the full size of the top-level root widget.